# Create a local variable for each row <tr> in a table with Angular2

Tags: angular

I have this following code in Angular 1.4

```
<tr ng-if="alerts.length > 0" ng-repeat="alert in alerts" ng-mouseover="del=true" ng-mouseleave="del=false">
  <td ng-bind="alert.name"></td>
  <td ng-bind="alert.desc"></td>
  <td ng-bind="alert.moduleType"></td>
  <td ng-bind="alert.triggerType"></td>
  <td>{{alert.alertActionType}}
        <a href="" ng-click="deleteAlert(alert);" tooltip-placement="right" tooltip="Delete" class="pull-right glyphicon glyphicon-trash" ng-show="del"></a>
  </td>
</tr>
```

The delete button will be shown based on 'del' variable for the mouse hover row.

I need to achieve the same in Angular 2. As of now i tried this following code.

```
<tr *ngFor="let alert of alerts" let del="false" (mouseover)="del=true" (mouseleave)="del=false">
  <td>{{alert.name}}</td>
   <td>{{alert.desc}}</td>
   <td>{{alert.moduleType}}</td>
   <td>{{alert.triggerType}}</td>
   <td>{{alert.alertActionType}}
      <a href="" (click)="deleteAlert(alert);" class="pull-right glyphicon glyphicon-trash" *ngIf="del"></a>
   </td>
</tr>
```

But on mouse hover all the row's delete button is shown.
 Need help on this.

Comment: `del` is a property of your component. There is a single component, but many rows. You want a variable that is specific to each row. So use `alert.del = true` / `alert.del = false`. Or better, with a meaningful name: `alert.deleteButtonShown = true`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

```
<tr *ngFor="let alert of alerts" let del="false" (mouseover)="alert.del=true" (mouseleave)="alert.del=false">
  <td>{{alert?.name}}</td>
   <td>{{alert?.desc}}</td>
   <td>{{alert?.moduleType}}</td>
   <td>{{alert?.triggerType}}</td>
   <td>{{alert?.alertActionType}}
      <a href="" (click)="deleteAlert(alert);" class="pull-right glyphicon glyphicon-trash" *ngIf="alert?.del"></a>
   </td>
</tr>
```

> because you are assigning local variable `del` to true on mouseover which is true for all in the loop, you have to set true for on on which your mouse is over